# How to search through Array in CosmosDB using SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a simple Array in a Document in my CosmosDB. An example of
`SELECT * FROM c` returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": "v1234567",
        "otherinfo": "othervalue",
        "log": [
            {
                "ts": 1572786079799,
                "e": "view1"
            },
            {
                "ts": 1572781436024,
                "e": "purchase"
            },
            {
                "ts": 1572786079799,
                "e": "view2"
            },
            {
                "ts": 1572786082033,
                "e": "view3"
            },
            {
                "ts": 1572781436024,
                "e": "purchase"
            },
            {
                "ts": 1572786082033,
                "e": "view4"
            }
        ],
        "_rid": "something",
        "_self": "something",
        "_etag": "\"something\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1572786088
    }
]
```

I want to achieve two things, but can't work out how to look inside the Arrays.

1. Return users (record) where `log[n].e = "purchase"`. I think I've acheived that with `SELECT * from c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.log, {"e": "atb"}, true)`
2. Return the users' ID, "otherinfo", and portion of the log after the first `e="purchase"` event found in the log. (in this case, view2, view3, purchase, view4).

I'm using the Document Explorer in Azure Portal. Have tried join queries, which fail instantly (because i'm probably getting it wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below stored procedure i tested successfully to implement your needs:

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.id,c.otherinfo,c.log from c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.log, {"e": "view2"}, true)',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
                console.log(i)
                var logArray = [];
                for(var j=0;j<feed[i].log.length;j++){
                    console.log(feed[i].log[j].e)
                    logArray.push({"e":feed[i].log[j].e});
                }
                feed[i].log = logArray;
            }

            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have used a "select *" in your join query and that is not supported.
try this query instead:

```
SELECT f.id, f.otherinfo, c.e
FROM f 
JOIN c IN f.log 
WHERE c.e = "purchase"
```